# Solving for the scaling factor in the hanging cable problem without knowing the length of cable

Tags: curves

A question relating to the "hanging cable problem" in which a cable hangs from two poles in the form of a catenary. Typically the problem is to solve for the sag or distance between poles given the length of the cable. My problem is different; given known equal height poles and known distance between them, with the cable tangent to the ground: can you solve for the scaling factor **a**?

$$y = a \cdot cosh   \left(\frac{x}{a} \right) - a$$

[image]

Comment: I think you can only solve it numerically, but that's easy to do. Wolfram alpha can give you an answer if you just input the equation

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I properly understood, knowing $x$ and $y$, you want to solve for $a$ the equation $$y = a \, \cosh   \left(\frac{x}{a} \right) - a$$
Let $a=\frac x z$, $k=\frac y x$ to make
$$k=\frac{\cosh (z)-1}{z}$$ To have an *approximation* using Taylor series
$$k=\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^3}{24}+\frac{z^5}{720}+\frac{z^7}{40320}+\frac{z^9}{3628800}
   +O\left(z^{11}\right)$$ Now, using series reversion
$$z=2 k-\frac{2 k^3}{3}+\frac{26 k^5}{45}-\frac{622 k^7}{945}+\frac{4042
   k^9}{4725}+O\left(k^{11}\right)$$